# Regarding sigma fields and its subsets

Tags: measure-theory

There is a subset of sigma field $G_2$, say $G_1 \subset G_2$. $G_1$ is proven to be a sigma field.
Does this necessarily imply that $G_1 = G_2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at all: the Borel sets of $\Bbb R$ form a $\sigma$-field $\mathcal{B}$, and the power set $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb R)$ of $\Bbb R$ is a $\sigma$-field, but $\mathcal{B} \subsetneqq \mathcal{P}(\Bbb R)$, as not every set of reals is Borel.

Answer (score 1):

No: If $X$ is nonempty, $\mathcal{G}_1 = \{\emptyset, X\}$, and $\mathcal{G}_2 = \mathcal{P}(X)$, then $\mathcal{G}_1$ and $\mathcal{G}_2$ are $\sigma$-fields with $\mathcal{G}_1 \subseteq \mathcal{G}_2$, but $\mathcal{G}_1 \neq \mathcal{G}_2$.

Comment: What exactly is P(X)?

Comment: @Huibong the power set of $X$, which is the set of all subsets of $X$.